# Should Rep points amount value be reduced over time?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I suggest that any rep awarded after a certain period of time should lose value. The reason is that I see so many one post wonders where a user posts one answer and gets thousands of rep.

A quick query on single answer/question high rep users will show what I mean, but unfortunately, I don't know how to do this on Stack Overflow.

One thing I have noticed is that there are not many answers these days that will get hundreds or even thousands of votes like some did when the site first started.

One possibility for the decrease in value:

- First Year   = 10 rep
- Second Year  = 8 Rep
- Third Year   = 6 Rep
- Forth Year   = 4 Rep
- Fifth Year   = 2 Rep
- Sixth Year   = 2 Rep

However, keep the rep value on the post to show that it is good as it is now.

Would this not provide more incentive for people to answer more questions?

One example of the most simple questions: [How do I calculate someone's age in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c) And just to clarify, not all posts are made community wiki like this one, hence my idea about the staggered rep count system.

[image]
Is this question worth the amount of rep points it has given the asker? As I said, keep the upvotes, but reduce their rep value. 1391 votes for such a simple question is a lot.

Otherwise it seems that Stack Overflow's mantra of a high rep user being a trusted member is literally crap, due to the fact that a user can gain thousands of rep from a single question or answer and not have any experience on the site. Is that the Stack Overflow we are all striving for?

Comment: People have enough of an incentive to answer questions as it is. So much so that they're happy to answer off-topic questions, bad questions, duplicate questions, etc. We don't need much more of that.

Comment: OK, so just keep awarding those one answer wonders rep then, great system!!! Keep it up! You obviously don't won't the site to keep evolving then?

Comment: https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/strawman (in b4 https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/the-fallacy-fallacy)

Comment: @BoltClock, oh, you are so funny, I almost laughed.

Comment: I'll be here all day.

Comment: @BoltClock, yep, seems you have nothing better to do... I on the other hand am building man, made of straw.....

Comment: Oh and now the revenge downvotes begin on StackOverflow, great site for sure. You mods can't do anything about that can you? Of coarse not. How blatant can you get, I post a meta post and instantly get DV'ed on SO!

Comment: *"there are not many answers these days that will get hundreds or even thousands of votes like the ones did when the site first started."* You mean, like the ones that have been around for 6 years have gathered over the past 6 years?

Comment: @CodyGray, Exactly, what did you not understand about my OP?

Comment: Also, there's no evidence of revenge downvoting. You got a downvote on a question you asked 5 hours ago. Very likely that someone who follows the [vba] or whatever tags just saw this question and downvoted it, completely independently of this Meta question.

Comment: It's not that I didn't understand, it's that your assumptions are wrong. Answers didn't get hundreds or thousands of votes 6 years ago. They have received those votes a few at a time over the past 6 years. You are solving the wrong problem.

Comment: If I look at this [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/612675) your request  seems to be centered around 17729 users. That are users with just one post and more then > 125 reputation.

Comment: @CodyGray, amazing timing, a few minutes or even less after I posted this question.

Comment: @rene, how about single posters and rep count?

Comment: The timing is not really that amazing, it just seems that way to you. There are a *lot* of users on Stack Overflow with voting privileges. In the spirit of @BoltClock, this is a [false correlation fallacy](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/false-cause).

Comment: @CodyGray, so what in that post is so warranting a downvote then?

Comment: How should I know? I didn't downvote it.

Comment: @CodyGray, fine, use your common sense then.

Comment: Sigh. I don't know anything about WPF and XAML. I'm not qualified to judge whether or not that's a good question. If you want to discuss it, ask a new Meta question about it. Use the tag [meta-tag:specific-question]. Back on topic: [here's a relevant question from Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279345/should-the-age-of-a-user-profile-determine-rep)

Comment: Regarding your edit: what you propose for that question has actually already happened. It was made "community wiki" back in August of 2011, and the asker hasn't gotten any rep from it since.

Comment: @CodyGray, but how many votes and rep did that post get before it was made a wiki. Plus not all posts are made communities.

Comment: Related: [Life isn't fair](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/202652)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, if you agree with me, let me know, otherwise why the link?

Comment: @KyloRen: I'm not following. I don't agree with you, which is why I voted accordingly. The link is there to provide context; over time voting reflects the usefulness of posts. You seem to be complaining about long-time posts gaining upvotes vs your chances of getting upvotes on a recent question, at which point that link is relevant.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, if I cared about rep, I would be answering everyday in VBA, but I don't. What I am saying is that simple question skew the rep count of people over time. I have seen much more complex answer by people with very few votes.

Comment: Yes, so the link is relevant.

Comment: Great having my answer deleted. How dare I. The OP, KyloRen, seemed to think I expressed his opinions very succinctly, so I would call it relevant, despite it not focusing on the narrow issue defined in the question (went broader).

Comment: @angorsaxon, Meh, I don't know why I even bother, ALL this site cares abut is rep theses days instead of helping people. There is only so many questions you can ask before any question after that is considered a duplicate, so I don't see how the site is going to prosper in the future if interaction is frowned upon. Especially for noob's to programming, they are the most unwelcome here(people will say otherwise, but the actions of the mob speak a thousand words). But, what do I care? It seems the mob has the last say here. Its a shame to, I DO learn a lot from here.

Comment: I think what they don't get is they should limit down-votes to like say 0... keep an internal count, but display 0. Let us not discourage people so much. And quit being so pedantic mods, you guys really have that much time on your hands? Just let some things go and be a kinder, gentler community.

Comment: @angorsaxon, I agree, where is the incentive for people to stick around if they are bullied on their first post?

Comment: *"ALL this site cares abut is rep theses days instead of helping people."* That is incorrect. There is virtually no one I know who actively participates here that cares one whit about reputation. Reputation doesn't keep you warm at night, it isn't good for anything at all. Helping people is the sole motivation for answering questions. Getting a lot of people whining about it doesn't do much to motivate us to answer *your* questions.

Comment: @CodyGray, Are you that blind or just pretending? So why is everyone so against reducing rep over time? If this site REALLY was just about helping people there would not so many people against this? Lets face it, many companies/people are using stack rep as a gauge for their programming prowess when getting jobs.

Comment: What we're against are the assumptions that you're making to justify your proposal, which I've repeatedly pointed out are false. I wish there were more companies that would use reputation as a gauge for programming ability. I haven't seen much evidence of this. It hasn't gotten me a job yet. Reducing rep over time won't actually solve the problem. The people that have lots of reputation didn't get it because there were more people upvoting years ago. They got it because they got lucky and answered the right questions that turned "hot".

Comment: @CodyGray, at this point I think we should agree to disagree. I know you are a good guy, I have seen your posts, but ,not everyone is like you on Stack. And I really mean this, have a good day. Cheers.

Answer (score 15):

A post is helpful regardless of the time it was posted on.

If someone finds the famous "[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)" thread useful, then *it is useful* and it should be rewarded according to its content and quality. I don't see any reason why the OPs (of both question and answer) should be rewarded differently as a function of time.

Comment: So all those "Help me I'm stuck" questions over 7 years ago with hunderds of votes are considered helpful? This site is so wrong it is not funny

Comment: @KyloRen I don't know what questions you are referring to.

Comment: @KyloRen: the same could be applied to your arguments. What evidence do you have that answers that *are not helpful* get upvotes?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, see my edit

Comment: Only they can place edits and not be down-voted into oblivion before doing so.

Comment: @KyloRen: that's a community wiki post, no rep is gained. It is also *not an answer*; I asked you for evidence that **answers** are not useful.

Answer (score 8):

Are there many questions/answers which garner more rep that the question/answer might objectively represent? Sure.

So what? As someone else said, [life *isn't fair*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202652/life-isnt-fair).

There is no perfect system. There will always be outliers, places where the system is not exactly working as intended. The presence of outliers *alone* does not mean that the system isn't working.

Yes, you can find questions/answers that have more rep than they genuinely deserve. But I can also find questions/answers that [genuinely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319146/c11-introduced-a-standardized-memory-model-what-does-it-mean-and-how-is-it-g) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new), that genuinely deserve all of that rep.

Why should we take that away from them? Just because some people managed to win the lottery, to get something they didn't deserve?