# Proposal for a tweak to reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list) today. It is the one and only question ever posted by its contributor. In the space of almost 10 years of inactivity, they have accumulated >20k reputation, and are rated as in the top 2% of contributors. No doubt it is a helpful question to a certain audience... but it has long been a community effort, and so is it not a stretch to say that the reputation is deserved?

I get that this is a Q&A site, and that there is value in the Q component as much as in the A component. But... the [stated purpose of reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) is to act as, well, reputation - to be **"earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about"**

Apparently [Life isn't fair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202652/life-isnt-fair) with regard to reputation. To me that's a cop out. I think we can do better...

Concrete proposal: limit the reputation gained from a question to N days after the user last posted either a question or an answer or an accepted edit to either. Suggestion: N=14. FAQ suggestion: change **"question is voted up: +10"** to **"... +10 (subject to activity - see below)"** and explain the constraints and the intent of them.

The intention is that doing this would have zero impact on anyone who is a regular SO contributor of genuine value. It is also intended that you can contribute a single answer, retire, and watch your reputation rise without limit. It encourages more meaningful engagement with SO by encouraging activity that helps improve questions and answers.

My intention is also that you could leave SO/SX for a period, return, and continue to earn value from old questions that you asked years ago - that the reputation accrues to a question's contributor when the contributor is actively contributing value.

Variation: make it N days after ANY activity so as to include the contribution of comments.

Counter-argument: this is a Q&A site, so edits to Qs and As are valuable contributions when accepted, whereas comments are too variable in nature to be a concrete indication of value. Valued contributors could/should be expected to contribute a question/answer/edit inside N days.

Comment: What problem are you trying to fix here?

Comment: The problem of trust. Otherwise: why does reputation even exist?

Comment: How is that a problem?

Comment: I still don't get why it is a problem that someone who wrote an awesome question/answer has a high reputation, no matter how active they are.

Comment: How is something not doing what it was supposed to do - indeed: highlighted as such - NOT a problem?

Comment: How is it not doing what it's supposed to do?

Comment: Convince me that the contributor has convinced their peers they knew what they were talking about.

Comment: let me give you an example of one of our best CSS contributor on the site: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry ... this user is no more active since 2017, you know why? because he's dead ... ([yes it's true, this not a joke](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36547685#36547685) ..). Should we stop rewarding this user because he can no more be active? should we stop his good answers from getting more upvotes because he's dead? that doesn't make any sense at all ...

Comment: What *possible* problem are you trying to solve with this other than "other people have more reputation than me"? I'll even copy over my comment from the [last question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398900/how-is-extremely-low-activity-leading-to-extremely-high-reputation-and-top-2-of) ([now deleted](https://i.imgur.com/r7FoNf7.png)) since I feel it's still relevant:

Comment: "*is it reasonable to continue giving the OP any credit at all for that "community effort*"?" let's flip this - should we discredit OP for producing a Q&A that helped thousands? OK, sure - I get the idea. There are some questions from the past that have gained immense popularity and we, in the present, can't possibly compete with them. I have felt the same way myself. But here is the thing - why would we need to compete? The main goal of SO is to be a repository for useful Q&As. So, strive for that. It just happens that some questions are useful for more people.

Comment: I think I have a 2 cents to add here. Reputation on SO are regarded as a means of bestowing privileges on someone. As you gain more and more reps, SO assumes that you're more and more familiar with the site so you're granted privileges to take certain decision on the part of curation/moderation. So I think this question does raise a valid point there. However, I'm not sure how a limit can be imposed on the number of reps gained against a Q/A for that will take away the incentive to edit the old posts for certain users.

Comment: @ABGR while I do agree that rep and privileges shouldn't be directly related, imposing some artificial limitations on rep is not the solution.

Comment: @VLAZ yup, Also as I noted doing that might make some users less enthusiastic about updating their old posts once it has reached a certain cap. So perhaps another solution can be thought about regarding linking reps with privileges.

Comment: Related proposal: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308203/should-reputation-points-be-calculated-via-a-sliding-time-window and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341125/should-rep-points-amount-value-be-reduced-over-time

Comment: @ABGR I don't mind *some* rep giving you access to privileges, however, I don't like that it's the *only* thing that determines it. If you hit X rep you're not automatically qualified for something. Rep loosely correlates with amount of usage of the site but cannot be equated. You can hit 3k rep without ever editing a post or looking at any reviews and you'll immediately have full edit privileges. We do have a sort of "progression" for some features - suggested edits are the "training mode" later to be replaced with full editing. Flags later become votes.

Comment: @ABGR This sort of progression should be utilised more - you get a more limited feature first then move on to the full one after some usage. That shows proficiency with the tool, not how much you've been voted on. We have this more directly expressed in the gold badges where it makes somewhat more sense - if you've shown proficiency with a given tag, you're trusted to unilaterally close as duplicates. I've some objections there but I'll leave them for another day - it does showcase a better approach to grant privileges.

Comment: @VLAZ yup I agree. Linking privileges with badges could be used to bridge the gap.

Comment: Should a dead person continue to gain reputation based on the answers they provided? Absolutely. But on the questions they asked? If you could show me a question here that had >100 upvotes, yet <10 answers, then you could convince me that questions had more value than answers. I doubt you can find that. But I give up - reputation is clearly a hornet's nest that nobody should ever dare touch :-(

Comment: @omatai "*But I give up - reputation is clearly a hornet's nest that nobody should ever dare touch*" yet again - I do not see what your proposal is even about. My only issue here is that it seems that it's just "I don't like that others gain more reputation than I do". It's self-centred as opposed to a change that aims to improve anything. I've yet to see any value to this proposal. Why does it matter if somebody is still submitting posts or not in relation to whether the older posts are valuable?

Comment: You can read it as self-centered, but that's your choice. I offered it 100% as a change that aims to improve something. The specific something is referenced *directly* to what the FAQ says that reputation is supposed to be about - **convincing your peers**. So far, literally *everyone* has ignored this pivotal fact. Being wilfully blind to that fact is also a choice - I would say that's where the selfishness lies here. *Nothing* I advocated would have had *any* effect at all on the **signal** of reputation, only on the **noise**. Please try reading what I wrote, not what you think I wrote.

Comment: "*The specific something is referenced directly to what the FAQ says that reputation is supposed to be about - convincing your peers.*" so, wait - if I *stop* participating, then my peers should be less convinced? I really don't get it. I can write the best, most comprehensive post in the history of computing *however* to really convince my peers, I have to I keep answering once a week/month/whatever. I don't even need to write deep or profound answers there - I can just go answer the most trivial of regex questions. Yeah, I ignored it because it makes no sense.

Answer (score 17):

No thanks.

Why should we stop rewarding someone for writing an awesome question, just because they're less active?

Does the fact I go on vacation for a month make my question less useful? Does that mean I don't *deserve* the reputation?

I see no problem that's being solved here. I see no reason to restrict rep gain for less active users.

Comment: See the clarification I was writing as you responded

Comment: And you could always set N=40, and take your vacation. Your reputation would remain, but users who write one novice question every year or two would not be rated as highly reputably as you. How does that NOT improve reputation in terms of being an indication of trustworthiness?

Comment: I think you're taking reputation points a little too seriously.

Comment: Reputation is a rough measure of community trust, @omatai - Stack has never claimed it was an accurate one

Comment: today, neither questions nor answer get more than 5 upvotes or downvotes for that matter

Comment: @nbk That is clearly untrue (although it might be correct on **this** site). I have a question on meta.se that repcapped and is still receiving up votes 6 weeks later...

Comment: it is of course, only my impression, but with 700 answers to the topic mysql, google can not find even 1 answer of mine. but is that google finds more "old" Q&A then the recent ones. So it is actually quite hard to get a high reputation. Further if you put here a software that detects dupe on mass, almost nobody would get any poin.ts anymore, but @Cerbrus is right, if you take the rep thing seriosly you get a coronary

Comment: @omatai or, in another perspective, why should my upvotes on a post matter less just because I stumbled upon it later than some folks?